# JIRA - Swimlanes add issue when Swimlanes Title as in label

Tags: jira, jql

I search:

- How add a issue into Swimlanes when the issue label contains the name of Swimlanes?
- What is the JQL Syntax to compare:
  `labels ~ Swimlanes.name`  return
  `Error: The operator '~' is not supported by the 'labels' field.`

Example:
Swimlanes Title: S50

Issue Labels: S50

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the operator **contains (~)** with the field **labels**. Because **~** searches for text in text fields.  Labels are a set of fixed terms, a select list rather than text.

Instead, you can use the JQL **labels = Swimlanes.name** in each swimlane. It will add an issue into Swimlanes when the issue label equals the name of Swimlanes

For example :

Swimlanes Title: S50

Issue Labels: S50

JQL : **labels = S50**